# Longer street segments in osm2po

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po, streets

I'm using osm2po to break up OSM map into routable segments, and pretty much always I want the streets to go from one intersection to another (or till some alley).

However, if underlying OSM map has a street that is already broken up into multiple segments (a lot of times arbitrarily), I'm ending up with the same segments in my map, so even some streets with no alleys coming into them are split up in two or three parts. Is there some way to instruct osm2po to merge these smaller segments into one?

Example:

Map that I generate, with Kolpingplatz separated into two segments (orange and red). 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAgXS.jpg

Same street in OSM, composed of two segments:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX6OT.jpg

And in reality, I just want that segment of Kolpingplatz to be one street segment, not two.

Comment: The road in your example (https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/147410122, https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/23574788) has been split because the parking conditions differ. Joining these two roads will loose this information. The same will apply to almost all similar cases in OSM.

Answer (score 1):

In order to "repair" unnecessarily split ways the entire graph must be known. But this is the last step in the conversion chain. In the early steps this information is not present. But even if it was, it would be quite hard to detect and fix all streets of the whole planet.
However, these "cuts" may have a reason. Mostly they exist because there are different tags on the segments, such as speed or restrictions.
If it's just wrong, then feel free to correct the data in OSM directly.